# Black screen in game

Tags: windows-10, crash, window, components

I'm getting black screen while gaming. Sometime it can take 5 hours before it comes or less
To fix that i need to shutdown my computer from my power button.
**I have windows 10**
In eventviewer

[image: Image link]

[image: Full event viewer]

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    - <System>
          <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}" /> 
          <EventID>41</EventID> 
          <Version>3</Version> 
          <Level>1</Level> 
          <Task>63</Task> 
          <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
          <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-26T20:04:25.659088000Z" /> 
          <EventRecordID>2760</EventRecordID> 
          <Correlation /> 
          <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
          <Channel>System</Channel> 
          <Computer>DESKTOP-2JTJQJ8</Computer> 
          <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
      </System>
    - <EventData>
          <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
          <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
          <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
          <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
          <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
          <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
          <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
          <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
      </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Sometimes it went black for only 2-3 seconds and after that window message `graphic card not responding and recovered` but not anymore.
Now my whole pc froze

1. I didn't build my pc I bought it from store.
2. I did factory reset
3. I have drivers and AMD Catalyst control center

There's no problem in normal use but after couple of hours gaming it happens

Comment: try all steps from this KB page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience that is a graphic card seeing its last days.

Try some troubleshooting; Try using another graphic card (or something else, less graphic intensive, but cpu/HDD-intensive) if this still happens in the same frequency it could be anything from CPU, RAM or even HDD. Else, this is probably true.

Answer (score 0):

It could be faulty graphic card. You are having similar issues I had before my graphic card died. You can try to clean your PC from dust, and check for any damage to your card.

Comment: I cleaned my whole pc this week. Could it be faulty drivers? My pc worked perfectly 2 years before i started installing my drivers with iobit driver booster

Comment: you didn't try to reinstall drivers before asking here? if you didn't go download drivers from official site. how old is pc?